# tensorflow: Tensorflow Lite latency performance on x86_64 confusion

Tags: tensorflow

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution : Linux Ubuntu 16.04 and Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8100 CPU
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): binary
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.12.0
- Python version: python-2.7.12
- Bazel version: installed from binary
- GCC/Compiler version: installed from binary
- CUDA/cuDNN version: CPU version
- GPU model and memory: CPU version

**Describe the current behavior**

Download "Mobilenet_V1_1.0_224" from "https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models" and run latency test on original frozen model file and tflite file conerted by "Lite Tools".

***frozen model test***

```
# some code to import graph from frozen model file

input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
output_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1:0')

test_case = load_test_data(data_file, resize)
res = sess.run(output_tensor, feed_dict={input_tensor: test_case})

s = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(1000):
    res = sess.run(output_tensor, feed_dict={input_tensor: test_case})
e = timeit.default_timer()
print("avg cost {} s".format((e - s)/1000))
```

and I got avg cost *0.0266642200947* s

***tflite model converted by Lite***

```
# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.contrib.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_file)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

print(input_details)
print(output_details)

# Test model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_size = (input_shape[1], input_shape[2])
print("size: ", input_size)

# input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
input_data = load_test_data(data_file, resize)

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

print("Got {} by prob: {}".format(labels[np.argmax(output_data)], np.max(output_data)))

s = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(200):
    interpreter.invoke()
    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
e = timeit.default_timer()
print("avg cost {} s".format((e - s)/200))
print("Got {} by prob: {}".format(labels[np.argmax(output_data)], np.max(output_data)))
```

Then I got avg cost 0.0471310245991 s
and for the quanted model even got avg cost 0.133453620672 s

I'm expecting a latency performance promotion, but it seems opposite.

Is TensorFlow Lite tools just optimize models for specific embedding platforms such as what official bechmark running on?
Or I'm doing something wrong lead to such performance degradation?

Comment: Our CPU kernels are currently optimized for ARM mobile, not x86. So performance on that can be unpredictable. Another variable is the existence multi threaded kernels.

Comment: @suharshs : is this still the case ? Or have we optimized for x86 platform as well.

Comment: @suharshs : might be helpful to update the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization with the platforms based benchmarking as well